# How to make array add Obect

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I mean this, I have some data

```
var some1Data =[1,2,3,4,5,]
```

and I want insert other object like this

```
var someArray=[]
var examLists= new array();

some1Data.forEach(function(v,i){
    someArray[1].key:some1Data[0]
}
```

How do I make Object?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: [MDN: Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var some1Data =[1,2,3,4,5];
var someArray=[];

some1Data.forEach(function(v,i){
   someArray.push({[i] : v})      // push object in array, use i as key and v as value
});

console.log(someArray)
```

Working with [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: some1Data.forEach(function(v,i){
    someArray[ I mean here ].key:some1Data[0]
}
How to increase this point?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score -1):

Javascript has several options in editting arrays.

use this url: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

look at array methods,you can use push to add to the back and something else to add to the front